# Когда "по данным" не вводное?

Tags: пунктуация

Как объяснить невыделение запятыми "по данным производителя" в следующем предложении?
*Если по данным производителя автомобиль должен проходить тяжелое бездорожье, то на практике он с трудом заезжает на тротуар.*
Ср.: *Если, по данным производителя, автомобиль должен проходить тяжелое бездорожье, то на городских дорогах он вряд ли уместен.*

Answer (score 1):

"Если по данным производителя автомобиль должен проходить тяжелое бездорожье, то на практике он с трудом заезжает на тротуар". Без словосочетания "по данным производителя" фраза теряет ясность смысла, поэтому его нельзя ни убирать, ни обособлять.

Предложение с тем же смыслом может иметь еще следующую форму: "В то время как по данным производителя автомобиль должен проходить тяжелое бездорожье, то на практике он с трудом заезжает на тротуар". Это СПП с придаточным сопоставительным, и это сопоставление при изменении структуры предложения может оказаться непонятым.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь "по данным производителя" = "в теории", поэтому запятые не нужны.
Союз "если ..., то" здесь как-то не очень. Ощущается условие, а его здесь нет.

Answer (score 0):

Не вводное - в первом случае, потому что сделан смысловой акцент именно на то, что автомобиль должен быть проходимым, согласно данным производителя. И тут "по данным производителя" никак не выбросишь без нарушения смысла. Во втором же случае, в принципе, его можно выбросить и внимание на нем не заостряется.

Comment: Мне нужно научное объяснение. Аргументов о "нарушении смысла" в учебниках что-то не припомню. Обычно речь идет о нарушении структуры предложения. Можно ли считать структуру "Если автомобиль должен проходить тяжелое бездорожье, то на практике он с трудом заезжает на тротуар" настолько уродливой, что без "по данным" не обойтись? Может, возможны другие аргументы?